# Problems with client side ajax applications in sharepoint-2010 tutorial

Tags: asp.net-ajax, sharepoint-2010

Does anyone have obtained good results following this tutorial? http://www.endusersharepoint.com/EUSP2010/2010/05/12/client-side-ajax-applications-in-sharepoint-2010-%E2%80%93-part-3-asp-net-ajax-templating-101/

there are code snippets that don't work and missing files on referenced download links

The tutorial explain how can you work with ajax client side application on sharepoint

The error has to be in these sections

```
<asp:content id="PageHead" contentplaceholderid="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
<style type="text/css">
    .sys-template {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
<script src="../Scripts/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax/Start.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax/MicrosoftAjaxDataContext.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax/MicrosoftAjaxTemplates.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax/MicrosoftAjaxAdoNet.js" type="text/javascript"></script> </asp:content> 

<asp:Content ID="Main"  ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain"  runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
    Sys.require([
    Sys.components.dataView,
    Sys.components.openDataServiceProxy,
    Sys.scripts.jQuery
    ]);

    Sys.onReady(function () {
        var dataContext = $OpenDataServiceProxy('/_vti_bin/ListData.svc');

        $create(Sys.UI.DataView,
            {
                autoFetch: true,
                dataProvider: dataSource,
                fetchOperation: "Clients"
            },
            {},
            {},
            $get("userStoriesList")
        );
    });

    //Sys.Application.add_init(pageInit);
</script>

<ul id="userStoriesList" class="sys-template">
    <li>{{ Title }}</li>
</ul> </asp:Content>
```

thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

ok in order to make this works i just change a line

```
var dataContext = new Sys.Data.OpenDataServiceProxy("/_vti_bin/listdata.svc");
```

instead of this

```
var dataContext = $create(Sys.Data.DataContext, { serviceUri: "/_vti_bin/ListData.svc" });
```

and adding this reference

```
<script src="../Scripts/MicrosoftAjax/MicrosoftAjaxOpenData.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but I'm not happy with the solution